# Double curly brackets in html mean

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I was analyzing a code of a php website and I found this type pf html  with double curly braces.
what does it mean.

```
<div class="vp_dash_links">
    <h4><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="currentColor" d="M9,22A1,1 0 0,1 8,21V18H4A2,2 0 0,1 2,16V4C2,2.89 2.9,2 4,2H20A2,2 0 0,1 22,4V16A2,2 0 0,1 20,18H13.9L10.2,21.71C10,21.9 9.75,22 9.5,22V22H9Z" /></svg> {{LANG comments}}</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{{LINK dashboard}}" data-load="?link1=dashboard">{{LANG dashboard}}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{LINK video_studio}}" data-load="?link1=video_studio">{{LANG videos}}</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="{{LINK comments}}" data-load="?link1=comments">{{LANG comments}}</a></li>
        <?php if ($pt->config->usr_v_mon == 'on' || $pt->config->sell_videos_system == 'on' || $pt->config->payed_subscribers == 'on') { ?>
            <li><a href="{{LINK transactions}}" data-load="?link1=transactions">{{LANG earnings}}</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($pt->config->movies_videos == 'on' && PT_IsAdmin()) { ?>
            <li <?php if (!empty($_GET['videos_type']) && $_GET['videos_type'] == 'movies') { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>
                <a href="{{LINK video_studio?videos_type=movies}}" data-load="?link1=video_studio&videos_type=movies">{{LANG movies}}</a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

please help

Comment: This sort of notation is popular with MVC-oriented templating engines like Twig. These tags will be replaced at run time by values passed to a view renderer.

Comment: You found a template PHP file, there is still a process where need to be read and replace those "Fields" the double curly brackets. It could be anything, just a separator from the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a part of PHP.

You need to figure out what templating engine is used in your project. Something like Twig, Blade etc.

It is also possible that such constructions are parsed and transformed on the front-end by some js-framework like VueJS, Angular or similar.